# cURL PHP to Plain cURL

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to connect my Rails app to a third-party API. In their example code, the code to connect to their service is all in PHP. I'm not familiar with `PHP`.

This is the code:

```
<?php

// Token generation
$timestamp = time();
$uri = "https://api.website.com/post.json";
$password = "somePassword";

$security_token = sha1($timestamp.$uri.$password);

// Webservice call
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $uri);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$post = array();
$post["timestamp"] = $timestamp;
$post["security_token"] = $security_token;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($post));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

// USE THIS CODE TO CHECK THAT SSL CERTIFICATE IS VALID:
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "path/to/certifcate/file/certificate.crt");

$ret = curl_exec($ch);

// Check response
if(curl_errno($ch)) {
    curl_close($ch);
    die("CURL error: ".curl_error($ch));
}

$http_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
if($http_code != 200) {
    die("Server error, HTTP code: $http_code");
}

curl_close($ch);

// Parse response
try {
    $json = json_decode($ret);
    var_dump($json);
}
catch(Exception $e) {
    die("Failed to decode server response");
}

?>
```

Any help to convert this to plain `cURL` would be appreciated and thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't see any Ruby code here.

Comment: @miken32 I forgot to add it before, but I added it. usually, I have the API key inside the url and thats what "allows" to get the data, but this part: $security_token = sha1($timestamp.$uri.$password); is confusing me

Comment: What's confusing about it? It's some strings sent to a function. PHP documentation is at https://php.net/sha1. Your Ruby code shows no attempt to make a proper request, there isn't even a POST body included.

Comment: I saw ruby code was wrong I'll post the correct one soon @miken32

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I did it and it worked good.

```
uri = URI.parse("https://apilink/post.json")
pass = 'supper-password'
timestamp = Time.now

token = Digest::SHA1(timestamp + uri + pass)

request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri)
# request.body = "timestamp&security_token"

req_options = {
    use_ssl: uri.scheme == "https",
}

response = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port, req_options) do |http|
  http.request(request)
end

render json: response.code
```